# Trying to query an array

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that has an id of a function that references to another table that has the name of the function (Funcao in Portuguese, as is presented in the code).
I want to print the name of all the Functions next to the name of the person that has that function.

basically the code of the whole program is for the user to write something in a search bar and show it dinamicaly, as the user presses a key, results show up.
Here is the part that is giving me errors. (the search_string variable is the field where the user writes.)

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM utilizadores WHERE nome LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%"';

$result = $tutorial_db->query($query);
while($results = $result->fetch_array()) {
    $result_array[] = $results;
}
```

The query above takes the name of the user.

```
$query2 = 'SELECT * FROM funcoes WHERE id_funcao="'.$result_array["id_funcao"].'"';
$result2 = $tutorial_db->query($query2);
while($results2 = $result2->fetch_array()){
    $result_array2[] = $results2;
}
```

This one takes the id of the function of that user, and tries to query to get the name of the function.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this your error `(the search_string variable is the field where the user writes` ?

Comment: The error is: Notice: Undefined index: id_funcao in C:\xampp\htdocs\b\pesquisa\search.php on line 57

Comment: why not use `JOIN` and fetch all data through single `SQL` query?? would be easy to manage in `PHP` too!! :)

Comment: It is a best practice to check before assigning any values , `isset($result_array["id_funcao"]) or @$result_array["id_funcao"] or !empty($result_array["id_funcao"])` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easiest way to do it is by using a join

```
SELECT
  utilizadores.nome,
  funcoes.funcao
FROM
  utilizadores
  JOIN funcoes ON (utilizadores.id_funcao = funcoes.id_funcao)
WHERE
  utilizadores.nome LIKE "%<query>%"
```

then you have 1 array containing the name and function of a person within a single query